# http: invalid Host header in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, celery

I am a total newbie in AWS, and I have launched a EC2 instance to run a dockerized project. My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.10.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:6379
    env_file:
      - .env
  celery_worker:
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A repo_sync worker --beat -l info
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

Celery settings:

```
from datetime import timedelta

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://celery_worker:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_EXTENDED = True
CELERY_IMPORTS = ('main.celery_tasks',)
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'sync_all': {
        'task': 'sync_all_task',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=60 * 10).seconds,
    },
}
```

When running docker-compose up -d, I run into the following error:

> http: invalid Host header
> What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the issue you're facing, but:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://celery_worker:6379/0'
```

should be:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
```

From which container the log comes from?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan have you try that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but it still yields the same error

Comment: The logs come from celery_worker container

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan would you mind editing your question and sharing more logs from your celery_worker? I would love to see the broker establish connection and exceptions if there's any

Comment: How should I see the logs?

Comment: Remove the -d flag from the docker-compose up command

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan did you manage to see the logs? do you want to share them?